# Can I play the Final Fantasy XV mobile app without spoiling elements of the main game?

Tags: final-fantasy-15, final-fantasy-15-a-new-empire

Just ordered FF XV, and it's currently coming in the mail.

There's also a Final Fantasy XV Mobile game, can I play that without spoiling the elements of the story of the main game?

Comment: I haven't played much of *FFXV: A New Empire*, so I can't fully say, but I haven't seen any spoilers towards the main game.

Comment: Also, but can't ask it as a question by itself: Is it good?

Comment: I enjoyed it - it's similar to Clash of Clans (if you've played that)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on information from [Polygon article](https://www.polygon.com/2017/6/29/15889192/final-fantasy-15-a-new-empire-ios-android-impressions-it-sucks) and [FFXV: A New Empire](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Fantasy_XV:_A_New_Empire), you can play the mobile game without spoiling anything from the main game.

> There’s little in common between A New Empire and the game it’s based on

and

> The game is set in the universe of Final Fantasy XV and features an alternate story which focuses on the development of Insomnia as a kingdom.

Further more, FF XV: A New Empire was not developed by Square Enix. It was developed

> by Machine Zone, Inc. (MZ), under the name Epic Action LLC, licensing the Final Fantasy name from Square Enix

FF XV: A New Empire follows similar play styles of the companys other games, like Mobile Strike and Game of War: Fire Age, while licensed under the FF XV title and universe.